# Is JobTracker a single point of failure too (besides NameNode) in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. In hadoop, I know that when a NameNode fails the entire Hadoop framework goes down. So it's a single point of failure in Hadoop. Is it same for JobTracker? Because if the JobTracker goes down, there would be no daemon to contact Namenode after a job submission and also no point for running the TaskTrackers. How is this handled exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JobTracker is a single point of failure in MRv1. In case of JobTracker failure all running jobs are halted (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobTracker).

In YARN, Resource manager is not a single point of failure.

If you need MRv1, you can use MapR distribution, which provides the JobTracker high availability (http://www.mapr.com/resources/videos/demo-hadoop-jobtracker-failing-and-recovering-mapr-cluster).

Comment: can you please also guide me that in which conditions job tracker or name node fails?

Comment: hardware failure, lost of network connection, operating system crash and so on.

Comment: ya right and also it fails most of the time coz of name node goes to safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

Jobtracker HA(High Availability using Active and Standby) can be configured in Cloudera Hadoop distribution. See the following link, this feature is available from CDH4.2.1 onwards:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-High-Availability-Guide/cdh4hag_topic_3_1.html

The same can be configured in Hortwonworks distribution also 
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.2/bk_hdp1-system-admin-guide/content/sysadminguides_ha_chap2_5_5.html

In MR2 master service is ResourceManager, which is not Single Point of Failure

Answer (score 0):

Yes job tracker is a single point of failure. In case of namenode failure, secondary namenode will take a charge and act as namenode. In MR-II, there is a resource manager concept introduced. YARN has no. of resource manager, if one fails another resource manager will take a charge.One resource manager is active and other resource manager's are in stand by mode.